# error in docker build - Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 unzip amd64 6.0-21+deb9u1 404 Not Found

Tags: docker, debian, apt-get

I am doing a docker build on my MacBook Pro and it always keeps failing with following error:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Suggested packages:
  zip
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  unzip
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 170 kB of archives.
After this operation, 547 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 unzip amd64 6.0-21+deb9u1
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/u/unzip/unzip_6.0-21+deb9u1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install unzip' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

docker version:
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b

MacOS: Mojave 10.14.6

Dockerfile snippet:

```
FROM debian:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ca-certificates
RUN apt-get install unzip
```

The build works fine in our travis CI which is using docker-ce=17.09.0~ce-0~ubuntu

Any suggestions on how to debug it further? Initially we thought it may be a temporary issue on debian side but the problem has persisted so likely an issue with my environment.

Comment: Does combining the three `apt-get` commands into a single `RUN` command help?  Does the `docker build` output include the line "Using cache" above what you quoted?

Comment: ```Sending build context to Docker daemon  91.25MB
Step 1/10 : FROM debian:latest
 ---> 8d31923452f8
Step 2/10 : RUN apt-get update```
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3140f7361780

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the three `RUN` lines you show into a single command:

```
FROM debian:latest
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y \
      ca-certificates \
      unzip
```

There's a combination of two things that leads to that 404 error.  On the one hand, Docker will cache individual Dockerfile steps: it sees that, starting from `debian:latest`, it's already `RUN apt-get update`, so it uses the version of that command from yesterday.  On the other hand, Debian updates their repositories fairly frequently with very minor updates (see the `+deb9u1` part of that version number) and when they do they delete the previous version from their repositories.  This combination means you can be in a sequence where you're using a cached version of the `apt-get update` index, but the package version it mentions doesn't exist any more.

Combining these lines together like this means Docker will always run both `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` together; if you add a package to the list it will re-run the `update` step before trying to download things.  That avoids this problem, at the cost of a little extra download time when the package list changes.

Comment: thanks David. The change of combining the three RUN lines in to a single command works. I appreciate the detailed explanation that you shared.